# Loop insert an instance of a node into a doubly linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list, nodes

The way I have implemented my code doesn't throw any errors when compiling, but doesn't achieve my desired result which leads me to believe the nodes are not being linked correctly. The display function continually throws "linked list is empty!" even though the add function is correctly displaying the logic I want it to on the console. What am I doing wrong in the add function loop that is not linking these nodes correctly?

```
void List::Add()
    {
        cout << "[Add]~\n";
        int I = 0;
        while (I < maxSize)
        {
            Node createdNode = new node;
            createdNode->next = NULL;
            createdNode->data = initialArray[I];
            if(!startList)//no list
            {
                createdNode->prev = NULL;
                createdNode->next = current;
                startList = createdNode;
            }
            else //there is a list
            {
                current = startList;
                while (current->next != NULL)
                {
                    current = current->next;
                } //while not at end of list, current pointer is advanced until last node is reached
                current->next = createdNode;
                createdNode->prev = current;
            }
            cout << "[" << createdNode->data << "]";
            I++;
        }
        cout << "\nHave Been Added To The Linked List!\n\n";
    }


void List::Display()
{
    cout << "[Display]~\n";
    if (!startList) //no list
    {
        cout << "Linked List Is Empty!\n\n";
    }
    else //there is a list
    {
        current = startList;
        while (current->next)
        {
            cout << "[" << current->data << "]";
            current = current->next;
        }
    }
}//void display();

#pragma once
class List
{
public: //this is where functions go
    void Length();
    void Add();
    void Display();
    void GetFile();
    void Directions();
    void Sort();

private:
    typedef struct node
    {
        int data;
        node *next;
        node *prev;
    }*Node;

    Node startList = NULL;
    Node current = NULL;
};
```

Comment: I recommend discarding the concept of `current`. You will find the difficulty of keeping it meaningful exceeds the benefits of having it. Instead look at iterators and other tools to force the client to keep track of where they are in the list.

Comment: For the rest, draw the list out on paper exactly following the rules outlined in the code, then modify the drawing to match how the list must look in order to be usable and implement those changes in the code.